# Why Image in HTML Notepad Document is Not Showing in Browser

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make a small browser site from HTML using Notepad. The goal is to get this image on the screen:

[image]

This is where I am storing the file:

[image]

[image]

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p style="background-image: url('A/A.jpg');">
      Hi
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is what I get when I open it in Microsoft Edge
[image]

Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: you have to relative path for the image. put your html file and image in same same folder and use path `./A.jpg`

Comment: Did you put the html in `downloads` directory?

Comment: Do yourself a favor, run a local server and not use the file protool. I would also use VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to check if it works with this picture just to see if that works so.

```css
    .myBg{
        background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e6s5.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width:539px;
        height:357px;
        color:#ffffff;
        font-size: 20pt;
        font-weight: bold;
        border:1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<p class="myBg">
Hi
</p>
```